# I would like to manipulate the data from the views to / render (html) in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this view using generic in django and I need to manipulate it. But it seems that whenever I tried using **setattr** it doesn't manipulate/replace the data in the **queryset**.

view.py

```
class ArticleListView(ListView): #using the Generic ListView in django
    template_name = 'article/article_list_view.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.all()[:5]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        setattr(self.queryset[0], 'title', 'something') #Trying to change the title in the first element
        print(getattr(self.queryset[0], 'title')) #it outputs the old value
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

article_list_view.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <h5>{{instance.title}}</h5>
    {% autoescape off %}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p>{{instance.content| capfirst}}</p>
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue? Or maybe because it was immutable?

Comment: Do you want the updated title saved to your database, or are you just trying to overwrite it for this view?

Comment: I'm just going to overwrite it for this view. My intention is to create like slack/github/stackoverflow like for example if my content has '**' it has a bold text.  **bold**

Comment: Is this possible? I was planning to use render and put the context there and now the problem is that putting it on the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a challenge because according to [Django's docs on querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) "a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database". The first thing you and I both tried was grabbing the first object out of the queryset and setting the attribute. This doesn't help because the queryset itself isn't being evaluated until you iterate over it: `{% for instance in object_list %}`. When that happens the model instance will be retrieved from the database again.

The best solution I can see is to force the queryset to be evaluated before updating the model instance.

```py
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'article/article_list_view.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.all()[:5]

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        # Overwriting this method to receive exactly the same arguments as the original
        # https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.6/django/views/generic/list.py#L113
        if object_list is None:
            object_list = self.object_list

        if not isinstance(object_list, tuple):  # Force the queryset into a tuple so it's evaluated
            object_list = tuple(object_list)

        object_list[0].title = 'something'  # Update the instance's title
        return super().get_context_data(object_list=object_list, **kwargs)
```

This does have the downside of `article_list` won't be available in the context unless you explicitly set `context_object_name = 'article_list'` on your view, but you already weren't using that variable.

I've tested out parts of this code to verify that my theory is right, but I haven't run the code in it's entirety, so you might need to tweak things to get it working exactly as you want it.